# What is the definition/meaning of 'qualified' in the context of CSS? (csslint.net warning)

Tags: css, csslint

What is the meaning of 'qualified'? I'm getting this warning from csslint.net:

"Disallow qualified headings: Heading (h1) should not be qualified)."

The problem code in question:

```
.Layer2_InfoText1 h1 {
  margin:1.3rem;
}
```

What does this mean, and why is it considered a problem?

Comment: 15 seconds of searching: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-qualified-headings

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Looking for the relevant definition so I can make sense of that. There's 9 definitions for 'qualified' on Google a couple of which could make sense in context.

Comment: Qualified -> *"scoped to particular areas of the page"*. *"...when any rule contains a selector where the heading element is last"*. In your case, you've **qualified** the rule to apply to `h1` *only within elements with class `Layer2_InfoText1`*.

Comment: It makes sense now with that context.

Comment: CSSLint has always been an overopinionated and fundamentally useless piece of software. Delete it from your computer now.

Comment: Add a class to the h1 tag(s) and refer to that class instead of the tag name - the warning will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context 'qualified' refers to selecting of an element with CSS beyond the top level. h1 is qualified, therefore, in this example.

Its a style guide according to csslint.net